# "\n" ser transformado em "<br>" automaticamente

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de postagens em PHP com MySQL.
Preciso que as quebras de linha que o usuário inserir no `textarea` sejam convertidos em `<br />`.

A variável `$texto` (contém o conteúdo da postagem) vai para o banco de dados na coluna `conteudo` (tipo TEXT).

Quando o usuário quebra a linha no `textarea`, é adicionado automaticamente um espaço. Precisava substituir esse espaço por uma `<br />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nl2br

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
nl2br — Insere quebras de linha HTML antes de todas newlines em uma string

Descrição

```
string nl2br ( string $string )
```

Retorna string com `<br />` inserido antes de todas as newlines.

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente o que precisava! Obrigado! (quando der o tempo mínimo, aceito a resposta)

Comment: Recomendo que salve no bd a versão original com nl, e utilize a função na hora de exibir como HTML, é mais prático se precisar colocar o conteúdo em um textarea para edição...